# Combining Server Components and Client Components in Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js13

I am facing some issue in a Next.JS app.

This app has some server components already functionning as I expect.
Those components allow me to fetch data from a database.

Here is the code for the main component:

```
export default async function SentenceList({}:{}) {
    const theResult = await sentences()

    return <div>
        {
            theResult.map(item => (
                <div key={item.orderKey as string}>
                    <SentenceUnit sentence={item.sentence}
                                                english={item.english}
                                                french={item.french} />
                </div>
            ))
        }
    </div>
} /* End of SentenceList */
```

Up to this point all is fine. Problems come from now on.

I want to call the component above in a few various ways (passing it parameters). In other words it would become:

```
    export default async function SentenceList(
        {param}:{param: number}) {
        ... work according to value of param ...
    } /* End of SentenceList */
```

But to allow the user to set the value of the parameter to be passed to this server component I need a client component to set interactity to get the user input. And this is where troubles come.

I have tried to set a client component (see code below) from where I could get the user input and also call my working server component. But it does not work (at least, the way I do it).

```
    'use client'
    .....

    export default function SentenceDisplayMng() {
        const [transType, setTransType] = useState(1)
        const [typeChecks, setTypeChecks] = useState([false,false])

        return <div>
          <TranslatChoice
                    actionFunc={(v) => setTransType(v)} 
                    radChecks={typeChecks} />

            <SentenceList />
        </div>
    } /* End of SentenceDisplayMng */
```

Because of the presence of useState I have to set: 'use client'

But once I do that I am told that I cannot do such a thing. Precisely I get this error message:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.
```

Here 'use client' has indeed been added (to the Client Component), but that was not accidental.

F.Y.I. In the code above TranslatChoice is just a component made to get the user information via radio boxes, but this is rather irrelevant to the question.

What I am trying to do is basic enough so that other people are bound to have met the same issue before me and there must be a reasonably easy solution. Am I including the Server Components inside the Client Components in a wrong manner? Or is there some better way to do?

I hope some Next.JS expert will be able to give me some good tips here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add a server component as a child to client component, at least not like this. You can pass the server component as prop to client component but the parent of client component needs to be a server component. You can read more about it in the docs [Nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#nesting-server-components-inside-client-components).